# Если все input checkbox в классе - checked то элемент сделать cheked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть форма с чекбоксами, и есть отдельный чекбокс - отметить все [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает все гуд, но еще мне нужно, чтобы при загрузке страницы было условие - Если все чекбоксы конкретного блока "чекнуты" - чекнуть конкретный input - Все уведомления. Каким образом можно сделать это на jquery ?

Вот таким образом отмечаю все чекбоксы -

```
$("#notificationsettings-mail_all").change(function () {
  $("#notification_mail input:checkbox").prop('checked',$(this).prop("checked"));
  $('#notification_form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Выберите чекбоксы с селектором `:not(:checked)` и посмотрите на длину полученного списка

```js
$("#notificationsettings-mail_all").change(function() {
  $("#notification_mail input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  $('#notification_form').submit();
});

$("#notification_mail input:checkbox").change(function() {
  $("#notificationsettings-mail_all").prop(
    'checked',
    $("#notification_mail input:checkbox:not(:checked)").length == 0
  );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#notification_mail input:checkbox:first").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="notificationsettings-mail_all" type="checkbox" />
<label for="notificationsettings-mail_all">Check All</label>
<br />
<div id="notification_mail">
  <input id="check_1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <label for="check_1">Check 1</label>
  <br />
  <input id="check_2" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <label for="check_2">Check 2</label>
  <br />
  <input id="check_3" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <label for="check_3">Check 2</label>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: СПасибо! А как сделать то же самое, только + при загрузке страницы , а не по $("#notification_mail input:checkbox").change >

Comment: @VladShkuta вызвать вручную обработчик `onchange`. Отредактировал сообщение

Comment: @VladShkuta нужно подписаться на событие change у элемента $("#notification_mail input:checkbox").on("change", function(){ //что-то делать });

Comment: Сделал как у вас, работает, но. У меня checkbox стилизированы так, что checked плавно нажимается. Теперь после открытия странички я вижу как он делается checked. Походу по другому не будет?

Comment: @VladShkuta Поменяйте местами стилизацию и установку значения